# Is it possible to use DevEx 15.2 for Visual Studio 2015 and DevEx 16.2 for Visual Studio 2017 at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

I want to use DevEx 15.2 for Visual Studio 2015 and DevEx 16.2 for Visual Studio 2017 at the same time. I'm working on two projects. For the first project I'm using DevEx 15.2 in VS 2015 and for the other one I have to download DevEx 16.2 for VS 2017, so what if I download DevEx 16.2? Can I use DevEx 15.2 for VS 2015 and DevEx 16.2 for VS 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use DevEx 15.2 for VS 2015 and DevEx 16.2 for VS 2017?

Yes, you can. Because both these versions support mentioned versions of Visual Studio. For the detailed information take a look at the [Prerequisites](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8092/Prerequisites) page which contains information about system requirements for installing and using DevExpress WinForms Controls.

Note: You **can't have the different versions of DX DLLs in one project** simultaneously. To avoid any issues with converting the project from one version to another, use the [Project Converter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/ProjectConverter/2529/Project-Converter) tool.